# How to count all participants of each registration type?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to have a table that shows all the registration types associated with a conference, the price of each one and the number of registrations sold of each registration type. A table like:

```
Registration Type                  Price           Sold/capacity 
rtype1                              0.00$              2/40
rtype2                              5.00$             30/100
rtype3                              10.00$             20/50
```

The registration_types table has the name and the price, so is possible to get this directly.

The registration_types has also the column capacity.

But then the quantity of registrations sold of each registration type is not stored directly in any table. The participants table has all the participants registered in the conference like in the example below. So it should be necessary to count all participants of each registration type, for example in the table above there are two participants registered in the registration type "1" and two participants registered in the registration type "2".

Do you know how the query should be to achieve this context? Im not understanding how to get the count of each registration type in the participants table.

Participants table is like:

```
id     registration_id      registration_type_id      name        
1         1                        1                   Jake 
2        1                         1                   Jane
3        1                         2                   Paul
4        2                        2                    Ben
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT registration_type_id,
       count(*)
       FROM participants
       GROUP BY registration_type_id;
```

gives you the count of the different registration types in `participants`.

But I assume `registration_id` designates the conference. So you likely want to extend it to

```
SELECT registration_id,
       registration_type_id,
       count(*)
       FROM participants
       GROUP BY registration_id,
                registration_type_id;
```

giving you the count of registrations per conference and registration type.

Comment: Thanks, do you know why, to show the name and the price with "SELECT 
name, price, registration_type_id, 
       count(*)
       FROM participants, registration_types
       GROUP BY registration_type_id;" shows "Column 'name' in field list is ambiguous".

Comment: But with "SELECT registration_types.name, registration_types.price, registration_type_id, count(*) FROM participants, registration_types GROUP BY registration_type_id;" shows"Unknown column 'registration_types.price' in 'field list'"?

Comment: @John: You want to join the tables/query results than. But I cannot guess enough of the structure and meaning of `registration_types` and `participants`to answer that in greater detail. You should ask a new question giving the structure of the tables (as `CREATE TABLE` statements plus a description of the semantic) along with some sample data (as `INSERT INTO` statements) and a description of the result you want including an example result according to the given sample data, to get help with this.